# How to get location name from latitude and longitude in R for a complete dataset?

Tags: r, for-loop, geocoding, ggmap, reverse-geocoding

I applied this code to getting the area name from latitude and longitude for 17000 dataset:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Cat/Documents")
data <- na.omit
link <- matrix(NA, nrow = 17899, ncol=1)
duh <- list()
semi <- list()
add1 <- matrix(NA, ncol = 1, nrow = 17899)
add2 <- matrix(NA, ncol = 1, nrow = 17899)
add3 <- matrix(NA, ncol = 1, nrow = 17899)
for(i in 1:17889){
    link[i, 1] <- paste("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?",
                       "latlng=", sub(i,3), "MY API KEY", sep="")
    duh[i] <- list(readLines(link[i, 1]))
    duh[[i]] <- xmlTreeParse(duh[[i]], useInternalNodes = TRUE)
    duh[[i]] <- getNodeSet(duh[[i]])
    semi[[i]] <- xmlToDataFrame(duh[[i]], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    add1[1] <- semi[[i]][1, 1]
    add2[2] <- semi[[i]][2, 1]
    add3[3] <- semi[[i]][3, 1]
    final <- cbind(add1, add2, add3)
}
```

And I got an error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r"):
cannot open URL 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=MY API KEY': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request.
```

Comment: Consider adding all relevant tags to your question.

Comment: To be frank, I don't have the slightest idea what you were trying to achieve with your code, but I proposed a solution to the  title question. If you have any questions please do not hesitate to shoot me a message.

Answer (score -1):

Simple for-loop:

```
         lon      lat       name
1  16.373819 48.20817     Vienna
2  13.404954 52.52001     Berlin
3  37.617300 55.75583     Moscow
4 139.691706 35.68949      Tokyo
5   9.801697 52.47807 Isernhagen
6 114.057865 22.54310   Shenzhen
```

#### Code

```
library(ggmap)
register_key(key = "...")      # Your billing-enabled Google Maps API key

loc <- c("Vienna", "Berlin", "Moscow", "Tokyo", "Isernhagen", "Shenzhen") 
coord <- NULL

for (i in 1:length(loc)){
    coord <- rbind(coord, cbind(geocode(loc[i]), name = loc[i]))
}
```